# Add a tone as an Alert Tone rather than as a Ringtone

Tags: ios, notifications, customization, whatsapp.app

I have successfully added a tone to my iPhone 7, as explained in this Apple Communities [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7551897).

However it is getting added as a “ringtone” rather than as an “alert tone.”

How can I change it to an Alert Tone? It’s barely 1-second long. When syncing or creating the `.m4r` file, there is no option to select the type as either Ringtone or Alert Tone.

The reason I need this is to add a custom notification for a WhatsApp contact. WhatsApp only allows me to choose from Alert Tones.

So the way I see it there are two options:

1. Ask WhatsApp to allow to choose from Ringtones.
2. Add my own Alert Tone.

I am exploring option 2 here, because WhatsApp support isn’t being very helpful.

Comment: Does it really matter, when you can choose any ringtone as an alert anyway?

Comment: actually, i am trying to add custom notification for a whatsapp contact. Whatsapp 'Customization Notification" option allows to choose from alert tones only. so there are two options, 1) ask whatsapp to allow to choose a ringtone 2) be able to add my own alert tone. i am exploring option 2 here. for option 1, already sent mail to whatsapp support. they are not helping.

Comment: I've never used WhatsApp, so I've no clue how it works, sorry

Comment: This info would be better added to the original question, to save people asking the obvious first... as seems to have already happened... :/

Comment: Im on the same boat as the OP. Exactly the same for Whatsapp

Comment: Stupid company’s stupid application. I don’t wanna use the mulls’ privacy seller app but for my common folks. By the by, the inability is still matter.

Comment: in Telegram you can custom alert tone using mp3 from iPhone files. i hope Whatsapp developer would do so, bu i don't expect much either

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 11 it is not possible to create custom **Alert Tones**, only custom **Ringtones**.  iTunes itself only makes one **Media Kind** available for them: *Ringtone*. That cannot be changed.

You can assign both **Ringtones** and **Alert Tones** to any event under **Settings** → **Sounds & Haptics** on your iOS device.

As far as app-specific limitations are concerned, you’ll have to take it up to the developers of such apps, in this case WhatsApp. I doubt Apple will add that functionality, since it makes no difference to iOS itself.

Comment: i have given the reason in the comment in the question

Comment: somewhere i read that the duration of the tone matters, if the duration is less, it can be added as alert tone

Comment: is there a work-around to copy a tone to some folder so that apps can see it as alert tone

Comment: No, there isn't. iTunes isn't even aware of **Alert Tones**, just **Ringtones**.