# Custom notification tones for WhatsApp iphone12

Tags: ios, notifications, whatsapp.app

I know how to customize the ringtone on WhatsApp, however, when I try and customise the notification tone, the list to select from only includes the default Apple tones - i.e. Aurora to Synth and Bell to Xylophone.  That's very frustrating. The custom ringtones I've made using garage band or uploaded aren't listed as options (which they are on the ringtone list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. Under the hood, WhatsApp notification tones are Apple Alert Tones and not ringtones. This is why your list of options is restricted to the small subset that you've mentioned. Sadly, [you cannot create custom Alert Tones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258316/385841).